# How to share parametrized arguments across multiple test functions?

Tags: pytest

I have many test functions in the same file that share a common set of parametrized arguments, as shown in the code snippets below. When the number of test functions increases (>100), repeating those parameters for each test function doesn't seem to be efficient and can be error prone. Is there any way in pytest to define one set of common parametrized arguments and share it across all tests? Fixture is used to inject common data dependency. I wonder if there is any similar tool to inject common *arguments*.

```py
import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize('common_arg1', [0, 1])
@pytest.mark.parametrize('common_arg2', [2, 3])
@pytest.mark.parametrize('a', [0, 1])
def test_1(common_arg1, common_arg2, a):
    pass
    
@pytest.mark.parametrize('common_arg1', [0, 1])  # repetition
@pytest.mark.parametrize('common_arg2', [2, 3])  # repetition
@pytest.mark.parametrize('b', [0, 1])
def test_2(common_arg1, common_arg2, b):
    pass
    
...

@pytest.mark.parametrize('common_arg1', [0, 1])  # more repetition!
@pytest.mark.parametrize('common_arg2', [2, 3])  # more repetition!
@pytest.mark.parametrize('x', [0, 1])
def test_100(common_arg1, common_arg2, x):
    pass
```

Comment: What about declaring global variables? `common_arg1 = [0, 1]` and reuse it throughout the module.

Comment: The approach with global variables has two drawbacks: 1) cannot rerun each test function for all possible combinations of (common_arg1, common_arg2); 2) cannot capture the full parameter list for each test in a fixture since common_arg1 & common_arg2 are no longer arguments to test functions.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - you pass `common_arg1` to `parametrize`, e.g. `@pytest.mark.parametrize('common_arg1', common_args1)`.

Comment: I see what you mean now. With this approach, the parametrization statements are still needed for each test function but the actual parameter values are defined in a single place. The suggestion from the answer below goes a step further and save the need to repeating the @pytest.mark.parametrize() statements. Still, thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You could move all test cases into one helper class and put common decorators on top of that class. Decorators that are specific to some tests (methods) can be applied directly on them. Check the example below.

```py
import pytest


@pytest.mark.parametrize('common_arg1', [0, 1])
@pytest.mark.parametrize('common_arg2', [2, 3])
class TestParametrized:

    @pytest.mark.parametrize('a', [0, 1])
    def test_1(self, common_arg1, common_arg2, a):
        pass

    @pytest.mark.parametrize('b', [0, 1])
    def test_2(self, common_arg1, common_arg2, b):
        pass

    @pytest.mark.parametrize('x', [0, 1])
    def test_100(self, common_arg1, common_arg2, x):
        pass
```

Comment: This doesn't work when some functions don't take that common argument. Still pretty neat

Comment: I like this approach as many times when you need to use same `@pytest.mark.parametrize` in different places they're testing something similar, and this also groups the related tests together.

Answer (score 12):

As pointed by Kammil, best approach is to have a Test class, as an alternative to Kammil's approach, is to have a class attribute with your test data, by doing this way, you can have test methods that do not use common_arg1 and common_arg2 in your class. But you still need to mark the tests, but you do not need to rewrite all the parametrize parameters, and if you change the values from the class attribute it is reflected in all tests.

This is particularly useful if you are going to have test methods in the same class that do not need common_arg1 and common_arg2.

Bear in mind that if you decorate the class all the methods will have to have common_arg1 and common_arg2 as parameters, if you try to write a method that do not reference them in the method's args list you will get a `function uses no argument 'common_arg1'` error.

So to avoid this you can do:

```py
import pytest

class TestParametrized:

    common_args = ('common_arg1, common_arg2', [([0, 1], [2,3])])

    @pytest.mark.parametrize(*common_args)
    @pytest.mark.parametrize('a', [0, 1])
    def test_1(self, common_arg1, common_arg2, a):
        pass

    @pytest.mark.parametrize(*common_args)
    @pytest.mark.parametrize('b', [0, 1])
    def test_2(self, common_arg1, common_arg2, b):
        pass

    @pytest.mark.parametrize(*common_args)
    @pytest.mark.parametrize('x', [0, 1])
    def test_100(self, common_arg1, common_arg2, x):
        pass

    def test_1000(self):
        pass
```

Note that test_1000 will be successful and will not complain about not mentioning common_args1 and common_args2. You can also split common_args in 2 by writing two class attributes.

Answer (score 7):

Another approach is to use a parametrized `pytest` fixture. For a single parametrization it is easy to use plain `pytest`:

```py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(params=[0, 1])
def common_arg1(request):
    return request.param

@pytest.fixture(params=[2, 3])
def common_arg2(request):
    return request.param

@pytest.mark.parametrize('a', [0, 1])
def test_1(common_arg1, common_arg2, a):
    pass

@pytest.mark.parametrize('b', [0, 1])
def test_2(common_arg1, common_arg2, b):
    pass

@pytest.mark.parametrize('x', [0, 1])
def test_100(common_arg1, common_arg2, x):
    pass
```

If you wish to write this in a more compact way you can use `pytest_cases.param_fixture`:

```py
from pytest_cases import param_fixture

common_arg1 = param_fixture('common_arg1', [0, 1])
common_arg2 = param_fixture('common_arg2', [2, 3])
```

For multiple parametrization you may wish to use `@pytest_cases.fixture` in order to be able to use `@pytest.mark.parametrize`:

```py
import pytest
from pytest_cases import fixture

@fixture
@pytest.mark.parametrize('a', [0, 1])
@pytest.mark.parametrize('b', [2, 3])
def common_arg_multiple(a, b):
    return a * b, a - b
```

See [pytest-cases documentation](https://smarie.github.io/python-pytest-cases/) for details. (I'm the author ;) )

Answer (score 4):

In python you can assign almost anything to a variable, including pytest marks.

```
import pytest

COMMON_ARG1 = pytest.mark.parametrize('common_arg1', [0, 1])
COMMON_ARG2 = pytest.mark.parametrize('common_arg2', [2, 3])

@COMMON_ARG1
@COMMON_ARG2
@pytest.mark.parametrize('a', [0, 1])
def test_1(common_arg1, common_arg2, a):
    pass
    
@COMMON_ARG1
@COMMON_ARG2
@pytest.mark.parametrize('b', [0, 1])
def test_2(common_arg1, common_arg2, b):
    pass
    
...

@COMMON_ARG1
@COMMON_ARG2
@pytest.mark.parametrize('x', [0, 1])
def test_100(common_arg1, common_arg2, x):
    pass
```

This particularly helps when you have a mix of commonly used arguments.

If they are all the same, like your example, its better to use a test class as shown in other answers, but if you have a lot of repeated params that are used in different combinations, this can be easier to manage.

If you use them across different test modules, you can even centralize them and import from that.

```
 from central_args import COMMON_ARG1, COMMON_ARG2
```

Comment: @cuhor said `Is there any way in pytest to define one set of common parametrized arguments and share it across all tests?` So your answer is not proper.